# convert bitmap to binary data in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, bitmapimage

Now a days i am more into bitmaps and its conversion. This time i would like to convert my bitmap image to binary values (1,1,0,0,....,0,1,1).

I tried the below code snippet, with the help of some googling.

```
string bmpFilePath= @"C:\Sample.bmp";
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bmpFilePath);

short[,] array = new short[bmp.Height, bmp.Width];
Color color;
int binaryVal  = 0;
string strBinaryData = string.Empty();
for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++) 
{
     for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++) 
     {
    color = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);
    binaryVal   = Color.White.ToArgb() == color.ToArgb() ? (short)1 : (short)0;
        strBinaryData += binaryVal.ToString();
     }
}
//StrBinaryData contains the String of binary values.
```

I am using the monochrome bitmap image to get the binary data. The code looks perfect for me, but when i try to print the image with one of the API i am not able see the exact image.

I would like to confirm that, is this above code is fine enough. If yes, probably i am making mistake in further processing of that binary data.

Please help me in doing so.

Reason For fetching the binary data for a bitmap:
I have an API to use, which expects binary data of an image as input.
Now i am getting some wrong results. Just need to check the inputs are correct or not?

Comment: There isn't any way I can see where SO can help you here, you say your code works, but your mystery api doesnt support it? At the very least you need to mention the api

Comment: Your code for reading the image is OK. But where is the printing image codes that actually have problems? Did you forget to print the line endings '\n'?

Comment: Are you sure that your API wants a binary string, like "0100110101001111111011"? Or is it asking for a binary *stream*, which would actually be a `byte[]`, with each byte in the array corresponding to 8 pixel values? You need to show us the API.

Comment: Hi, Its on of the commands that i need prepare and send it to printer. Even the guide i got, they mentioned, pass the binary data next to the command as a string. Probably i have to check with the technical support team of the printer, where they would help me in answering the quesiton.

Comment: Hi Sayse, Tianyun, Jim... There are two parts in my task, one is sending the proper binary data to the API and second thing ensure the API handled correct. The reason i didnt mention the API is, its command based in printer understandable.Some thing like this. (^XA^FO100,100^GFB100,100,<binarydata>,^xz). Since things are not working for me, from this fourm i can only check for the binary data validation. Thanks for your suggesions and feeling sorry for uncompleted explanation in my post. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first the nitpicky things:

- You shouldn't be throwing files in c:\, though that may just be my
  pet peeve.
- It's `string.Empty`, not `string.Empty()`
- Using a StringBuilder instead of a string would likely be faster.  A simple set of optimizations run 1,000,000 times on a 10x10 bitmap changed from 423ms average to 120ms average.  Other optimizations would probably speed it up as well.

Now the major thing:

Your code starts reading the columns from left to right, then each row in each column.  The net result is that your resulting `11100010101010....` data looks like the picture rotated counterclockwise 90 degrees.

Hopefully that points you in the right direction.